# No SQL dependency tracking when running .NET services on Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

We have migrated almost all our cloud services (classic Azure) to Service Fabric, but there is still one thing missing in our new setup and that's the automatic SQL dependency tracking. In Azure Cloud Services I installed the AI agent according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/cloudservices) and when the environment variables were set appropriately, the dependency information was properly annotated with the SQL commands.

Now with Service Fabric the AI logging is fine, but the SQL dependencies are not annotated anymore. This is probably, because the AI agent is missing on these nodes. I tried the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-vm-vmss-apps) for VM scale sets, but I can't install the *Application Insights Agent (.NET Preview)* extension in my VM scale-set, because I don't use .NET IIS-hosted applications.

I also read [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query) about SQL tracking, but it suggests that I need to switch to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` which is a no-go, because this code is ancient. It still uses Linq-2-SQL, so this is not a viable option.

The only thing left to do would be to use the same approach as in Cloud Services and that is to make sure the AI status monitor is installed during VM provisioning and that the the VMs have the proper environment variables set. This is quite some work, so I was wondering if there is a simpler approach that is also a supported scenario?